# Hide a '<div>' depending on a javabean value

Tags: java, html, jsp, javabeans

As the title describes, I want to hide a div if the bean returns a specific value.
I have the following code, but doesn't work (it doesn't hide the div)

JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id="Product1" type="Model.Product" scope="request" /> 
    <script>       
            if(  "empty_val".equals(${Product1.name}))
            {   
                product1.style.display = "none";
            }
    </script>

    <div id="product1">
```

...

Servlet sends everything right but I cannot find the way to 'handle' the occasion of a specific bean value in order to hide the 'div'. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `<c:if>` with JSTL and display the DIV conditionally

```
<c:if test="${Product1.name eq 'empty_val'}">
 <DIV></DIV>
</c:if>
```

**See**

- [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Could you extend your answer please J.Joshi? I haven't used <c:> before :/

Comment: Actually, in this case needs 'ne' not 'eq'. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your bean already exists in a scope, then eliminate the `<jsp:useBean />` tag.

If your intention is to write the `div` to the page, but to set its display style to none:

```
<div id="product1">...</div>
<script>
<c:if test="${Product1.name eq 'empty_val'}">
    product1.style.display = "none";
</c:if>
</script>
...
```

If you would rather just not write the `div` to the page:

```
<c:if test="${Product1.name ne 'empty_val'}">
    <div id="product1">...</div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Is there any syntax error? 'Cause by using that it prints: 
            product1.style.display = "none"; on the output

Comment: Updated response to clarify the two options; one based on your initial question which seemed to take a CSS/JS approach to hiding the div, and one based on simply not writing the div to the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Actually, only the second option works, using the 1st one the div doesn't be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
// JavaScript ain't Java
if ("${Product1.name}" === "empty_val") {
    ...
}
```

...better to add a class (e.g. "hide") to the div depending on the server value, there's really no need for JavaScript:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: With the 'if' solution of JS I don't see any change, it behaves exactly the same ... :/